# How can I pin a Chrome window with specific tabs (and only those) to a MacOS Monterey desktop?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, window-manager

My usual workflow requires me to have about a half dozen "frequently accessed" web apps open at all times. I'm looking for a way to lock these pages onto an "Overview" Desktop in MacOS Monterey. I'd like to be able to have these tabs (and only these tabs) in a particular named Chrome window, lock that window to a persistent desktop, have it return after restarts, and not have any other tabs open in that window.

Is there any way to achieve this level of organization and consistency in the combination of MacOS and Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a dedicated chrome profile to the web apps you need and setting that window to fullscreen mode. This would prevent other apps from opening in that space and set it to it's own space, which isn't otherwise supported in macOS.

Check the "Reopen windows when logging back in" or set chrome to start on startup. I now have one profile opening in my first space normally and another opening in fullscreen in it's own space.